# Cookies and JSONP

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, jsonp

I have an issue with JSONP and cookies sent by the browser.

Actually, I have two websites : server1 and server2. I want my users to authenticate to server1 and when they go to server2, I would like to check (via a Javascript JSONP call to server1) if they are authenticated.

The authentication on server1 is managed by cookies and I thought that when making my call to server1 via JSONP, the browser would send the cookies and then the authentication would work. But it seems that the browser (FF) doesn't send the cookies to server1 when sending request via JSONP.

Does anyone know if browsers send cookies when requesting with JSONP ? If it is not the case, what would be the better solution to check in Javascript if a user is authenticated on server1 from server2 ?

Thanks for your answers,

Vincent

Comment: Load a hidden iFrame of Server2 on the server1 page and then get the cookies etc that you need in the iFrame. Pass the message back to the server1 via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on domain names of those servers. If they are `server1.example.com` and `server2.example.com` you can set for cookies to be dependent on domain `.example.com`. Then will be the cookies sent to both servers.

If you can not do it like I wrote, you will have to do some workaround. For example by iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Jakub said and to further explain what might be happening in your case. I'm assuming that you are having domains as server1.com and server2.com

So if you are setting a cookie from application which is on server2.com and doing a JSONP request to application which is on server1.com from server1.com, it will send cookies if they were set previously from server1.com. Otherwise it would not send any cookies which were set by server2.com. Actually the browser is making request to the server1.com from application of server2.com which is exactly same as server2.com requesting a JavaScript file from CDN or any other server. Hence it won't send any of server2.com cookies, otherwise it would become big security issue with the browser.

Hope it makes sense.